# Whatsapp Web not forwarding videos

Tags: video, whatsapp

I am unable to forward videos on whatsapp web since the last week. A small error symbol appears with the forwarded message that says "Couldn't send this message" when I hover my mouse over it. I can use all other whatsapp functionality. I can even send videos by uploading. Text and picture messages can be forwarded as usual, only there is a problem in the video. The message stays like this indefinitely. Other messages are sent and received correctly after this one.

1. Is anyone else facing this issue?
2. Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Screenshot indicating "You deleted this message"]

Comment: I started to face the same time around the same date. I believe it's related to some time de-synchronization. Usually only cleaning up all the cache for the whatsapp web solves this. Caveat: sometimes this will request you to scan the QR code again.

Comment: cleaning up the cache of what? the browser on the computer?

Comment: Yes, the cache of the browser in the computer where you're running the WhatsApp web. Additionally, sync the computer clock.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it looks whatsapp has stopped forwarding using web. first download on local storage and then only forward.

Comment: The issue still persists. Is there any way we can know if Whatsapp is working on this problem? Or even they know the problem exists?

Comment: This approach is very painful when I want to send something to several people. I have to manually upload the video for every single person. It consumes a lot of time and effort.